# JavaScript - How to dynamically create a nested array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am provided with a string `B1-FEOL-SPUTTER-0015`, the string will be split up by `-` (the dash) then used to build up a nested array of objects. This is the original tree:

```
[{
  "text": "B1",
  "nodes": [{
    "text": "FEOL",
    "nodes": [{
      "text": "SPUTTER"
    }, {
      "text": "COATING"
    }, {
      "text": "EXPOSING"
    }, {
      "text": "DEVELOP"
    }, {
      "text": "PLATING"
    }, {
      "text": "BOND"
    }]
  }, {
    "text": "BEOL",
    "nodes": [{
      "text": "GRINDING"
    }, {
      "text": "BALLDROP"
    }, {
      "text": "PROBING"
    }, {
      "text": "BACKCOATING"
    }, {
      "text": "MARKING"
    }, {
      "text": "SORTING"
    }, {
      "text": "TUG"
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "text": "B2",
  "nodes": [{
    "text": "FEOL",
    "nodes": [{
      "text": "SPUTTER"
    }, {
      "text": "COATING"
    }, {
      "text": "EXPOSING"
    }, {
      "text": "DEVELOP"
    }, {
      "text": "PLATING"
    }, {
      "text": "BOND"
    }]
  }, {
    "text": "BEOL",
    "nodes": [{
      "text": "GRINDING"
    }, {
      "text": "BALLDROP"
    }, {
      "text": "PROBING"
    }, {
      "text": "BACKCOATING"
    }, {
      "text": "MARKING"
    }, {
      "text": "SORTING"
    }, {
      "text": "TUG"
    }]
  }]
}]
```

I have tried using recursive functions by entering the new values into `.forEach(manipulateTree)`. However I couldn't get it to create new nodes in the array which should be done in the `else` statement.

```
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
import util from 'util'

// This is avaliable in the link below, leading to pastebin
let tree = require('./server/configs/tree.json')

// The values I used to test:

// This works
// const newBranch = 'B1-FEOL-SPUTTER-0015'

// This doesn't
const newBranch = 'B3-ASDF-DSDF987SDF7-0015'

const locations = newBranch.split('-')

let nodes = {}

let iteration = -1
const manipulateTree = branch => {
  iteration++
  // Found node
  if (branch.text === locations[iteration]) {
    // Check if the iteration is second last in the branch array
    if (iteration === locations.length - 2) {
      branch.nodes.push({
        'text': locations[iteration + 1],
        'location': locations.join('-')
      })
    } else {
      // If not then the recursive function will continue operation
      if (branch.nodes && branch.nodes.length > 0) {
        const found = branch.nodes.find(node => node.text === locations[iteration + 1])
        if (found) {
          branch.nodes.forEach(manipulateTree)
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    console.log('No such node')
    if (iteration === locations.length - 1) {
      branch = {
        'text': locations[iteration],
        'location': locations.join('-')
      }
    } else {
      branch = {
        'text': locations[iteration],
        'nodes': []
      }
    }
  }
  return branch
}

if (tree && tree.length > 0) {
  tree.forEach(manipulateTree)
}

console.log(util.inspect(tree, false, null, true))
```

The end result that I want is this:

```
[{
  "text": "B1",
  "nodes": [{
    "text": "FEOL",
    "nodes": [{
      "text": "SPUTTER"
    }, {
      "text": "COATING"
    }, {
      "text": "EXPOSING"
    }, {
      "text": "DEVELOP"
    }, {
      "text": "PLATING"
    }, {
      "text": "BOND"
    }]
  }, {
    "text": "BEOL",
    "nodes": [{
      "text": "GRINDING"
    }, {
      "text": "BALLDROP"
    }, {
      "text": "PROBING"
    }, {
      "text": "BACKCOATING"
    }, {
      "text": "MARKING"
    }, {
      "text": "SORTING"
    }, {
      "text": "TUG"
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "text": "B2",
  "nodes": [{
    "text": "FEOL",
    "nodes": [{
      "text": "SPUTTER"
    }, {
      "text": "COATING"
    }, {
      "text": "EXPOSING"
    }, {
      "text": "DEVELOP"
    }, {
      "text": "PLATING"
    }, {
      "text": "BOND"
    }]
  }, {
    "text": "BEOL",
    "nodes": [{
      "text": "GRINDING"
    }, {
      "text": "BALLDROP"
    }, {
      "text": "PROBING"
    }, {
      "text": "BACKCOATING"
    }, {
      "text": "MARKING"
    }, {
      "text": "SORTING"
    }, {
      "text": "TUG"
    }]
  }]
}, { // This hear is the end result I want if there is no such node from the original tree
  "text": "B3",
  "nodes": [{
    "text": "ASDF",
    "nodes": [{
      "text": "DSDF987SDF7",
      "nodes": [{
        "text": "0015",
        "location": "B3-ASDF-DSDF987SDF7-0015"
      }]
    }]
  }]
}]
```

Comment: I don't understand the end result you want. Are you sure that's the correct pastebin URL? Can you put the desired result in the question instead of a link?

Comment: Woah! Not sure how that link changed but I have updated it.

Comment: You're just given `B1-FEOL-SPUTTER-015`, where is all the rest of that result coming from?

Comment: `forEach` doesn't do anything with the return value of the callback function, what's the point of `return branch`?

Comment: @Barmar The extra data is just testing if I already have those `nodes`, will it insert the end data in the correct place. This is done using the `newBranch` which works, because there is already nodes created for that branch. However, if I were to create nodes then it doesn't work.

Then the question about the `forEach`, I don't quite understand why but when I return a value to it, it edits the original array. If you use the `newBranch` which works and output the `tree` variable, you can see that `B1-FEOL-SPUTTER-0015` is inserted into the correct place.

Comment: The problem as stated — take a string and make a nested object — seems much simpler that what that pastbin link suggests. It seems like you have a bunch of strings and they all need to fit in the one structure.

Comment: Just for clarity, I removed all past data that was in the `tree.json` file.

Comment: @Barmar as you can see the output is this: https://pastebin.com/GFxXdsT4. Which I know is very confusing, because as stated in the documentation that it `forEach` loop doesn't return anything.

Comment: You're modifying the object you pass in with `branch.nodes.push(...)`.

Comment: You're taking a tree that's already in the JSON file, then this function is supposed to add something new to it from that string? It's hard to understand precisely what you're trying to add. Can you post a simple input tree and explain what you're trying to add to it?

Comment: @Barmar So [this](https://pastebin.com/TwVRV3Tn) is the tree that is already in the JSON file. I want to use this string `B3-ASDF-DSDF987SDF7-0015`, to create this [end result](https://pastebin.com/LciJTMwE).

Comment: Please put the clarification in the question, not a comment. Post the actual data, not links.

Comment: @Barmar updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the tree structure and a path, you just need to iterate the path and keep track of where you are. If you end up someplace that doesn't exist yet add it and continue. You can keep track of the index so you know when you've hit the last item and should add the `location` rather than the `nodes` array:

```js
let tree = [{"text": "B1","nodes": [{"text": "FEOL","nodes": [{"text": "SPUTTER"}, {"text": "COATING"}, {"text": "EXPOSING"}, {"text": "DEVELOP"}, {"text": "PLATING"}, {"text": "BOND"}]}, {"text": "BEOL","nodes": [{"text": "GRINDING"}, {"text": "BALLDROP"}, {"text": "PROBING"}, {"text": "BACKCOATING"}, {"text": "MARKING"}, {"text": "SORTING"}, {"text": "TUG"}]}]}, {"text": "B2","nodes": [{"text": "FEOL","nodes": [{"text": "SPUTTER"}, {"text": "COATING"}, {"text": "EXPOSING"}, {"text": "DEVELOP"}, {"text": "PLATING"}, {"text": "BOND"}]}, {"text": "BEOL","nodes": [{"text": "GRINDING"}, {"text": "BALLDROP"}, {"text": "PROBING"}, {"text": "BACKCOATING"}, {"text": "MARKING"}, {"text": "SORTING"}, {"text": "TUG"}]}]}]

const newBranch = 'B3-ASDF-DSDF987SDF7-0015'

let components = newBranch.split('-') 

let nodes = tree                                    // nodes is the current array
components.forEach((text, i) => {
    let current = nodes.find(i => i.text == text )  // find matching item
    if (!current) {
        current = i == components.length - 1        // if no matching item add it 
          ? {text, location: newBranch }
          : {text, nodes:[] }
        nodes.push(current)
    }
    else if (!current.nodes) current.nodes = []          
    nodes = current.nodes  
})

console.log(tree)
```

Comment: Thank you Mark, that really helped. I didn't think it would be that simple, I really over-complicated the problem